# How do we call a map $F$ such that $F(g\cdot p)=\varphi(g)\cdot F(p)$?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups acting on sets $M$ and $N$. Suppose that there is a group homomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ and a map $F:M\to N$ such that
$$F(g\cdot p)=\varphi(g)\cdot F(p)$$
for all $p\in M$ and $g\in G$. **How do we call such a map?** Is there a standard terminology?

When $G=H$ and $\varphi$ is the identity we say that $F$ **intertwines** the actions, or that $F$ is **equivariant**. Is it standard to use either of these words in the more general case? Like **"$\varphi$-equivariant"**, or something similar?

Comment: I would call that $G$-$H$ equivariant by $\varphi$ (and omit the "by $\varphi$" when the context was clear), but I'm not a geometer so I wouldn't take that as authoritative.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply an equivariant map, but the target is a bit different. Given an $H$-set $N$ and a morphism $\varphi : G \to H$, you get a $G$-set $\varphi^* N$; it has the same underlying set as $N$, and the action is prescribed by $g \cdot n := \varphi(g) \cdot n$. Then $F$ is by definition a $G$-equivariant map $M \to \varphi^* N$. If the morphism $\varphi$ is implied from the context, then you can omit it from the notation if you want.

Comment: The tags intended to show in which context the OP is working, which could possibly change the answer. Different fields have different conventions. It is clear that $F$ is equivariant with respect to the induced action of $G$ on $N$, but that's not giving a convenient terminology for such situations.

Comment: @user354997 Yes it does. The terminology is "$G$-equivariant". If you really want to be precise, say "$G$-equivariant wrt $\varphi$", though that's often unnecessary. I work in algebraic topology (where manifolds and Lie groups appear frequently), and this is the terminology I'm familiar with. I honestly don't expect different terminology to exist. Sometimes the simplest answer is the correct one... (I find it rather weird that you talk about "the OP" in the third person.)

Comment: As someone who works with Lie groups almost exclusively, I would just refer to such maps as equivariant.